# How to use loadnibnamed to pushviewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm writing a program that uses a NavigationBar.

I am using the project from this website 
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/

Usually, we push view controllers onto the navigationController. In my case, my xib connects to a class which is an object

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface PageControlExampleAppDelegate : NSObject  {
UIWindow *window;
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
BOOL pageControlUsed;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *viewControllers;

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender;
```

The problem is that because this is not a viewController, I'm unable to push it onto the navigationController.

The view is loaded using loadNibNamed, the object loads with awakeFromNib.

My problem is that when I call the loadNibNamed, it opens this object and I'm unable to come back to my previous view as the navigationBar is gone. This view seems to load itself on top of everything.

I've tried creating a new class which is a viewController and has an object of this ContentController but it would then load the new viewController (which is empty). If i call loadNibNamed from the new viewController, the new view still comes on top of everything.

1- What would be the best way to push this object (which opens up a view) onto my navigationController?

2- How would I make this contentController into a UIViewController instead of an object and would it still look and work the same as being an NSObject?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

i did not understand clearly what u said.
but for navigation controller try this
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];

Comment: The navigation controller is not hidden. Just that when calling the object, it seems that it gets instantiated on top of everything else prior to it rather than pushing onto the navigation controller and still showing the navbar